# Jquery horizontal sliding caption over adjacent div

Tags: jquery, slide, caption

I have been futzing with this for several days and could use some insight to get it working. What I need to do is have two images side-by-side, then have a hover effect on each image to slide a caption over the other image. I keep working from examples to slide a caption over the image that is hovered, but for some reason I can't even get that to work. I'm sure I'm missing something and I don't want to use a plugin because, despite my difficulty, this should be simple enough to add to my code.

Here's a fiddle with the code I am currently working with: http://jsfiddle.net/paulmz/h8L82/1/

Here's a code snippet (I don't know why this is mandatory):

```
    $('#activeSub2Left img').hover(function() {  
    $(this).find('.captionRight').stop().animate({ right: '470' }, { duration: 1600});  
    }, function() {  
    $(this).find('.captionRight').stop().animate({ right: '0' }, { duration: 1600});  
}); 

$('#activeSub2right img').hover(function() {  
    $(this).find('.captionLeft').stop().animate({ left: '470' }, { duration: 1600});  
    }, function() {  
    $(this).find('.captionLeft').stop().animate({ left: '0' }, { duration: 1600});  
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `.captionRight` and `.captionLeft` in the `img` when you should be looking in the `parent()`:

```
$('#activeSub2Left img').hover(function() {  
  $(this).parent().find('.captionRight').stop().animate({ right: '470' }, { duration: 1600});  
}, function() {  
  $(this).parent().find('.captionRight').stop().animate({ right: '0' }, { duration: 1600});  
}); 

$('#activeSub2right img').hover(function() {  
  $(this).parent().find('.captionLeft').stop().animate({ left: '470' }, { duration: 1600});  
}, function() {  
  $(this).parent().find('.captionLeft').stop().animate({ left: '0' }, { duration: 1600});  
});
```

Comment: Thanks- your suggestion of adding the .parent() plus tweaking the left/right positions fixed it.